# return javascript variable value to objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have seen some examples of how to read javascript from objective c. which im trying to use to return a dynamic value from a web page to a string in objective c.

```
[exerciseWebViewA loadHTMLString:@"<html><head><title>Untitled Page</title></head><body><div style=\"border:solid 1px red; width:300px;\"><script type=\"text/javascript\"> var myVar = \"one two three\";</script></div></body></html>" baseURL:nil];

NSString *example = [exerciseWebViewA stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(function() { return myVar; })();"];

NSLog(@"script value is: %@", example);
```

If i amend 'example' to @"(function() { return 'hello'; })();" it does write 'script value is hello' to the log. Am I going around this the right way?